# What does 2xMOPP really mean

Tags: power-supply, analog, isolation, compliance, medical

I am a student and I am designing a medical device that has a type CF applied part.

I know the specifications that the applied part must comply (4kV of insulation, 8mm of creepage, <10μA patient leakage current, 2xMOPP), but I don't understand what 2xMOPP means in practice. I know the definition is two means is patient protection and that it requires double insulation or reinforced insulation, but I don't know how to design a power supply that complies with that.

Does double insulaiton just mean I have to insulate the part twice? So can I use two isolated DC-DC converters (that don't provide 2xMOPP) that have 4kV of insulation in series?

Sorry if I seem a bit lost, but reading IEC 60601-1 isn't answering my questions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Does double insulaiton just mean I have to insulate the part twice?

Kinda, but...

> So can I use two isolated DC-DC converters (that don't provide 2xMOPP) that have 4kV of insulation in series?

...no, this is not what double insulation means.

Basically, your power supply should guarantee a shock protection in case of a failure i.e. if something happens on primary (HV, grid, mains, whatever) side the user shouldn't get shocked. This is primarily done with a transformer and a grounded metal shielding. For details google "Basic insulation", or `IEC Class I`.

Double insulation (a.k.a. reinforced insulation, `IEC Class II`) brings another layer of insulation in addition to basic insulation. This generally means putting the circuitry in a plastic cover. Therefore, a Class II device doesn't require a ground connection or a grounded metal shield.

For 2xMOPP, as you are already aware, the primary-secondary insulation must be 4 kV. This is primarily done on the transformer and the PCB layout. I'm not going to dive into details here as they are out of the question's scope.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So how can I achieve the 2xMOPP? I had the idea of using two NXJ1S0305MC-R13 (5.2kV isolation with 1xMOPP) in series but as you explained that isn't allowed. I don't want to use a 2xMOPP isolated DC-DC converter because they are very expensive. I just need 1 or 2 W for a 5V supply.

Comment: @fox_rafa I didn't say "not allowed", it's just not what is meant. Also it's impractical. If you are thinking about cascade connection of two 1xMOPP supplies then go for it. As long as you get the required insulation it's fine.

Comment: Wait, so 2xMOPP just means that I need to comply with the higher specs, not that I need to implement specific methods of isolation? So as long as I comply with 4kV of insulation, the creepage distance and the clearance distance, leakage current... My device complies with 2xMOPP?

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing a medical device, you need to comply with IEC 60601-1.

If the insulation is under stress, mechanical or environmental it will have more requirements than the ones I described below. Also the pollution degree of the environment has an effect on the nominal values. You need to read through the standard and the appendixes and evaluate what is relevant to your application.

Section 8.8 describes requirements for insulation, table 6 pointing out the test voltages for insulation. So for example insulation of a 50 V DC part of a circuit requires a test voltage of 500 V for One MOPP and test voltage of 1000 V for Two MOPP. So if your wire has a rating of 1000 V, it should offer Two MOPP, but it needs to be tested, if it is relevant for safety.

Considering AIR CLEARANCE and CREEPAGE DISTANCE (Caps used, to clarify the terms come from the standard), Table 12 in IEC 60601-1 tells you what distances are required for two means of patient protection. The distance doesn't always have to be continuous.

Test voltages for MOPPs are derived from Table 7 of the same standard.

Air clearances from mains parts are described in tables 13 and 14.

Power supply capacitors between mains and secondary have special requirements in chapter 8.5.1.2

Comment: Wait, so 2xMOPP just means that I need to comply with the higher specs, not that I need to implement specific methods of isolation? So as long as I comply with 4kV of insulation, the creepage distance and the clearance distance, leakage current... My device complies with 2xMOPP?

Comment: It's safety related if the hazard is contact to patient, so you also need to test according to the test voltages. If there's no heating or stress you don't need anything "special", if you comply with the gap requirements and pass isolation test.

Comment: *by testing I mean have it certified by a Certified Body, who'd do the testing.